# Find correct CSS tags for r-selenium

Tags: r, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, rselenium

I've used [this](https://analyticsprofile.com/business-analytics/learn-web-scraping-and-browser-automation-using-rselenium-in-r/) tutorial to learn about [RSelenium](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium). It works well for me.

I now tried to use that method on another page (Github), but I'm not sure how to find the CSS tags that focus the mouse on the correct field.

```
library(RSelenium) 
driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome") # start browser
remDr <- driver[["client"]] 

# Go to desired webpage
remDr$navigate("https://github.com/login")

login_id <- remDr$findElement(using = "css",  "login_field")
login_id $sendKeysToElement(list("my_login_name"))
```

If I use the Selector Gadget, it tells me the tag for the email/username box is `#login_field`.

If I `inspect` that part of the webpage, I'm told that the following bits correspond to that box:

```
<input type="text" name="login" id="login_field" class="form-control input-block" tabindex="1" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autofocus="autofocus">
```

But if I run the above code, I get the following error message:

```
Selenium message:no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"login_field"}
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=70.0.3538.16 (16ed95b41bb05e565b11fb66ac33c660b721f778),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)

Error:   Summary: NoSuchElement
     Detail: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I would appreciate your help how to correctly pick the CSS tags to enter. Thanks!

Comment: It might be a good idea to use a different website as an example. If you scroll to the bottom of https://github.com/robots.txt you'll see it explicitly has a valid technical control that informs programmers that scraping is prohibited. I'm not aware of pre-Microsoft GitHub fining anyone but post-Microsoft GitHub may since post-Microsoft LinkedIn has successfully prosecuted numerous individuals. Plus, GitHub has an API, so scraping it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Ok, agreed. Not a good example webpage to try this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the legal stuff, it probably works with `remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "login_field")`. So `using = "id"` instead of `using = "css"`

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the *Username or email address* field on the webpage `https://github.com/login` you need to induce *WebDriverWait* and cann use the following `CSS_SELECTOR`:

```
input.form-control.input-block#login_field
```

A *Python* example:

```
driver.get("https://github.com/login")
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.form-control.input-block#login_field"))).send_keys('ulima2_')
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: Github_Login]